# How to edit OVRPlayerController to allow for upward/downward movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Full disclosure: I've only been working in C# and Unity for about a week.

I'm building a program to explore a model of a solar system in VR. I've used the OVRPlayerController (from the OculusSampleFramework.UnityPackage) which that has given me 2-dimensional movement based on the direction the HMD is facing.

I turned off gravity and adjusted the move scale on line 264 of OVRPlayerController.cs so I could move without being grounded:

```
// No positional movement if we are in the air
if (!Controller.isGrounded)
    MoveScale = 2f;
```

So far I can only move on one 2D plane, but I want to allow vertical  movement. How do I include movement along the Y-axis using `q` and `e` keys, and based upon where the Player is facing?

[Here's a link to download the script I'm working on](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjAmp3dtJPVAhWL8oMKHWj3APAQFgg0MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.unity3d.com%2Fattachments%2Fovrplayercontroller-cs.125361%2F&usg=AFQjCNHhO3XGY00iHXsH8Ws4iBdcFMHGAA) minus the edit I mentioned.

Bonus question- will the Oculus Frameworks I'm using translate to the HTC Vive and other HMDs?